# How do I order a file of scores in Python?

Tags: python

Help with what functions to use

How to achieve this:

- Students' respective highest scores from highest to lowest.
- And finally the students' respective average scores from highest to
  lowest.
- Students' highest scores in alphabetical order

The final product should be:

```
Highest scores in descending order:
Name1 , HiScore1
Name2 , HiScore2
Name3 , HiScore3

Highest average scores in descending order:
Name1 , AvgScore1
Name2 , AvgScore2
Name3 , AvgScore3

Alphabetical order:
Name1 , AllScores
Name2 , AllScores
Name3 , AllScores
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean could you please explain

Comment: Without seeing what your file looks like, it is difficult to test an answer

Comment: could you give us more details like what the Test Scores Class#.txt files look like? Also what do you want exactly because you  mention alphabetical order and also highest score...

Comment: Once i have done what you have said I get the list in the opposite order. It goes in order of lowest to highest. How can I reverse this? And i appreciate the edit das-g

Comment: Edit your post with the exact formatting of the files please @user5959017

Comment: I have added them at the bottom @Seekheart

Comment: I need them to be in order of highest scores, highest to lowest. As another heading they will be ordered in alphabetical order with their high scores. Then in a final subheading they will be ordered by avg scores highest to lowest

Comment: I have edited in the files at the bottom of the post

Comment: Could anyone please help? @cricket_007

Comment: You seem to be asking a broad question. 1) read the strings from a file and sort alphabetically 2) read the numbers and sort descending,  and 3) read the numbers and average them by similar names. If you narrowed down your question, it would be easier to provide a simple answer

Comment: How do you want me to narrow this down?

Comment: Each is an individual question, so common practice on this site is to make separate posts, such as "I have a list of names, how do I sort them alphabetically?", and "I have a list of numbers, how do I sort them in reverse order?", and "I have a list of numbers, how do I average them?". Maybe you already know how to do all those things, but the great thing about programming is once you know how to do the small things, all you need to do is break the larger problem into those smaller problems.

Comment: I need to 1) sort the names by alphabetical order. 2) Sort the highest scores by descending 3)Find the average and order descending. If you could explain how to do one of them it would help me to progress so if you can help with any of the above I would be grateful

Comment: I can only post once every 90 minutes so I guess that won't work but i would appreciate if you took it one at a time and helped me with the objectives one at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample input - `file.txt`

```
rafay = 10
jamie = 2
jamie = 5
```

---

A function that returns data in this format, with the names in alphabetical order and scores sorted in reverse.

```
[('jamie', [5, 2]), ('rafay', [10])]
```

Takes in the filename as a parameter.

```
def get_scores(filename):
    student_data = {} 
    with open(filename) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            line = line.strip().split('=')
            name = line[0].strip()
            score = int(line[1].strip()) # If decimal scores allowed, change this line to float(line[1].strip())
            if name not in student_data:
                student_data[name] = []
            student_data[name].append(score)
            student_data[name].reverse()
    return sorted(student_data.items())
```

Call this function like so for each of your files to get each ordering of your data

```
alphabetical_names = get_scores('Test Scores Class1.txt')
highest_averages = sorted(alphabetical_names, key=lambda data: sum(data[1])/float(len(data[1])), reverse=True)
highest_scores = sorted(alphabetical_names, key=lambda data: max(data[1]), reverse=True)
```

Since you want to print in the same format each time, defining a helper method is useful

```
def print_func(x, y):
    print("{}, {}".format(x, y))
```

Then print out each listing

```
print("Highest scores in descending order:")
for name, scores in highest_scores:
    print_func(name, max(scores))
print("")

print("Highest average scores in descending order:")
for name, scores in highest_averages:
    print_func(name, sum(scores)/float(len(scores)))
print("")

print("Alphabetical order:")
for name, scores in alphabetical_names:
    print_func(name, scores)
```

Prints out like so

```
Highest scores in descending order:
rafay, 10
jamie, 5

Highest average scores in descending order:
rafay, 10.0
jamie, 3.5

Alphabetical order:
jamie, [5, 2]
rafay, [10]
```

Comment: Thank you but I need them separately, so there will be a heading, I will update the post to show you what i mean and where my code is right now. This really helped me also.

Comment: Yes please but preferably ordered separately and specify how it is ordered each time, thanks

Comment: @user5959017 Please see changes

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error and the typing position goes to when you call the function. highest_averages = sorted(alphabetical_names, key=lambda HERE(name, scores): sum(scores)/len(scores), reverse=True)

Comment: Ah, I was running Python 2, one sec

Comment: @user5959017 Alright, fixed. Not sure why Python3 removed that feature

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, is it too much to ask if you explained how you used things such as print("{}, {}".format(x, y)) and what they do?

Comment: The code is working perfectly btw and thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps

```
import operator

class extractData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.student_higest_marks = {}

    def get_content(self, filename):
        f = open(filename, 'r')
        data = f.read()
        f.close()
        return data

    def get_name_marks(self, content):
        for data in content.split('\n'):
            name = data.split('=')[0]
            marks = data.split('=')[1].strip()
            if name in self.student_higest_marks:
                self.student_higest_marks[name].append(int(marks))
            else:
                self.student_higest_marks[name] = [int(marks)]
        return self.student_higest_marks

    def cal_highest_marks(self):
        print "Highest scores in descending order:"
        highest_marks =  dict((name, max(marks)) for name,marks in
                              self.student_higest_marks.items())
        return sorted(highest_marks.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

    def alph_order(self):
        print "Alphabetical order:"
        return sorted(self.student_higest_marks.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))

    def cal_avg_score(self):
        print "Highest average scores in descending order:"
        avg_marks =  dict((name, reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,marks)/len(marks)) for name,marks in self.student_higest_marks.items())
        return sorted(avg_marks.items() ,key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

calObject = extractData()
content = calObject.get_content('Test Scores Class1.txt')
calObject.get_name_marks(content)
content = calObject.get_content('Test Scores Class2.txt')
calObject.get_name_marks(content)
print calObject.alph_order()
print calObject.cal_highest_marks()
print calObject.cal_avg_score()
```

hope you can loop over the results.

Comment: Why fear? Because OP clearly stated as new to learning python

Comment: just kidding . It was not meant to be taken literally.